# Is it possible to make click listener to item by string, not by position?

Tags: android

I have thousands of items stored in string-array and none of them are dublicate, And I have displayed them all in list. Now, I want to show the description if text clicked, I will show them in alert Dialog, Is there any way to store value as text click not by position? I don't like to use position to call them because if later I have to remove anything form the list then I have to remake all. So, I want is if text "vishnu" was  clicked then Make something called vishnu as id and  call the vishnu description according to text click not by position. Thanks in advance!! Here's something we do for position

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final NameViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(names.get(position).textView);

    holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I guess that you create an ArrayAdapter or something like this, if that was the case in your adapter you had a getItem that was the item display on the screen (no worries about the one you delete that was actualise with the screen) so for get your String you just had to do adapter.getItem(position).

Comment: You don't have to remake again, save your list in ArrayList and use that ArrayList to inflate the ArrayAdapter of ListView, and inside your click listener just use this name=arrayList.get(position);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a `Dictionary<string, string>` (choose a fitting class yourself. I am not sure but `Hashtable` probably works) that holds a Key value pair for each string, the key being the string itself and the value being the description you want to be shown when clicking that string.

Then you can use:

```
Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), myDictionary.get((string)view.getTag()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

to get the corresponding text.

**Edit 2:** How to use a Dictionary (an example):

```
//In Class
Dictionary<string, string> myDict;

//In ctor (or anywhere before you need it)
string nameString = "Marlon";
string descriptionString = "Some dude currently on stackoverflow.";
myDict = new Hastable<string, string>(); //Create dictionary
myDict.put(nameString, descriptionString); //Fill dictionary

//When you want to get your string
string output = myDict.get("Marlon"); //Get description
descriptionTextView.text = output;  //Put text at screen
```

**Edit:** Here you can find the [Dictionary docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Dictionary.html).

Comment: Can you please link the documentation/tutorial site? I was looking what exactly you mean. please link the site in your answer. I will accept it!!

Comment: Edited my question with the link to the docs. Dictionary is a great thing to use if you want to map things, like a describtion to a name or any other kind of key.

Answer (score 0):

Use getTag()/setTag to store data in view. For ex.:

Create new class with fields title and description

```
public class SomeObject{
   String title;
   String description;
}
```

outside of adapter create new list and fill it by this objects.
pust them to adapter.

```
ArrayList<SomeObject> mList = new ArrayList<>();

public void setData(ArrayList<SomeObject> list ){
     mList = list;
     notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final NameViewHolder holder, final int position) {
   holder.textView.setText(mList.get(position).title); // here is a title
   holder.textView.setTag(mList.get(position)); // push whole object to tag

   holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           SomeObject someObject =  (SomeObject)view.getTag(); // fetch object from tag of view
           Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), someObject , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your description is not empty?

Comment: No not Empty, I put description value  in strings.xml like <string name="Description"> This is discription</string> is this the correct way to put?